# appveyor - how to set environment variable using %HOMEPATH%

Tags: node-gyp, appveyor

I'm working on a node.js native addon project, instead of using binding.gyp, I'm using cmake, as my project depends on another cmake project.

I can use cmake to build the target(on my own windows 7), which needs to setup environment variables to specify library path include node-gyp and mysql. I got the mysql path(from appveyor doc), please correct me if I'm wrong.

But I don't know how to set node-gyp dir in appveyor environment, which is located in `~/.node-gyp` windows equivalent path. I tried below script, and it errored out at NODE_GYP_DIR line.

```
environment:
  # set variables
  NODE_GYP_VER: 0.12.7
  NODE_GYP_DIR: %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\.node-gyp
  LIBMYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR: C:\Program Files\MySql\MySQL Server 5.6\include
  LIBMYSQL_LIBRARY: C:\Program Files\MySql\MySQL Server 5.6\lib
```

My question is, can I assume `~/.node-gyp` windows equivalent path exists? How to set the path to my environment variable for my cmake? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `%USERPROFILE%` instead:

```
environment:
  # set variables
  NODE_GYP_VER: 0.12.7
  NODE_GYP_DIR: '%USERPROFILE%\.node-gyp'
  LIBMYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR: C:\Program Files\MySql\MySQL Server 5.6\include
  LIBMYSQL_LIBRARY: C:\Program Files\MySql\MySQL Server 5.6\lib
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Feodor Fitsner, but i still get the same error:

Error parsing appveyor.yml: (Line: 6, Col: 17, Idx: 115) - (Line: 6, Col: 18, Idx: 116): While scanning for the next token, find character that cannot start any token.

line:6 is: `NODE_GYP_DIR: %USERPROFILE%\.node-gyp`, col: 17 is `%`

Comment: i use `set NODE_GYP_DIR=%USERPROFILE%\.node-gyp` in the install section, and cmake passed, the output is `C:\Users\appveyor\.node-gyp`

Comment: It should be `NODE_GYP_DIR: '%USERPROFILE%\.node-gyp'` (the value is in quotes) - I've updated the answer.